# Pasar los parámetros de la vista al controlador guardar ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

tengo una duda como puedo pasar los parámetros de una vista a mi controlador guardarlos en un método llamado crea, gracias.

```
public ActionResult Crear(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View (objAlumno);
            }
            objAlumnoNeg.crear(objAlumno);
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Incluye el código con el que has trabajado para revisar dónde está fallando

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera ya lo deje arriba de la imagen, te comento que en el método me marca un erro en el nombre Crear, ya que no todas las rutas tienen un valor

Comment: El error que mencionas es porque el método espera que retornes un valor, que en este caso sería uno de tipo `ActionResult`... sólo con incluir el `return` antes de **objAlumnoNeg.crear(objAlumno);** dejará de darte dicho error

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera dice que no puede convertir explícitamente el método void

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta entonces... puedes incluir el código de **objAlumnoNeg.crear**? Asi puedo darte una respuesta más completa

Comment: De echo quiero crear el medo crear, pero no se como realizarlo, algún ejemplo

Comment: Ahhhhh es un método que no está creado... te dejo un link donde realizan un CRUD con MVC, trata de implementarlo y si no te funciona algo, acá estaremos para ayudarte :) https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Gracias, son muy amables, en esta pagina he aprendido mucho, estoy aprovechando las respuestas que me dejan.