# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

alguien me puede apoyar para resolver esto ya que no le encuentro, funcionaba bien, no regresa a la misma página pero si inserta en la Base de datos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

```
@model List<model.entity.Alumno>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "inicio";
    Layout = null;
}


<h1>Registro de Alumnos</h1>

<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var objAlumno in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@objAlumno.IdAlumno </td>
            <td>@objAlumno.Nombre </td>
            <td>@objAlumno.Apellido1 </td>
            <td>@objAlumno.Telefono1 </td>
            <td>@objAlumno.Estado </td>
            <td></td>


        </tr>

    }


</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisaste que el `Model` no esta nulo ó que cuando llamas a la vista le pasas el modelo, y de paso, esa preguanta se parece a la que hiciste no hace mucho. [Pasar los parámetros de la vista al controlador guardar ASP.Net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/220992/107347)

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Gracias por la respuesta, le preste la cuenta a mi compañero y posiblemente hizo una pregunta similar.

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias por la respuesta ya lo ando checando.

Comment: Tene cuidado. No es necesario prestar la cuenta, cualquiera puede generar un usuario en el sitio. tenes muchas preguntas con cero votos y cero respuestas aceptadas. Si seguis asi, el sistema puede bloquearte. Trata de aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron, o contestar tus propias preguntas si encontraste una solucion.